# Responsive background thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm attempting to build a theme in wordpress, but cannot figure out how to make the background image resize when resizing my browser window. When I get the image and set it to 'full', or any of the other preset sizes, I does not resize:

[image]

[image]

In my **front-page-php**:

```
<?php
    // check if the post or page has a Featured Image assigned to it.
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        // the_post_thumbnail();

        $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

        <header id="hero" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>') no-repeat center center fixed;"></header>

    <?php }
?>
```

and in my css file:

```
header {
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 95vh;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And it just simply stays the same.. So thankful for any help!

Comment: I take it you want the image to scale in size, depending on the size of the screen?  In that case, you will need to make your WordPress responsive.  One of the easiest ways to achieve this, is through the use of Bootstrap.  Are you familiar with how Bootstrap works and how you can place this into your WordPress Theme?

Comment: @Craig It worked with just adding "background-image" but thank you for your effort

Comment: No worries.  Great to hear you resolved your query.  Just in case you were not aware, you can answer your own question and tick as 'Accepted'. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easier way to get the post's thumbnail url. Also, it'd be better to set the `background-image` property in the `style` attribute:

```
<?php
    // check if the post or page has a Featured Image assigned to it.
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

        // the_post_thumbnail();
        $backgroundImg = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full'); ?>

        <header id="hero" style="background-image: url('<?= $backgroundImg; ?>');"></header>

    <?php }
?>
```

& the CSS should be:

```
header {
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 95vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Kelvin! I just had to change to "background-image" <3